# Need to Manipulate pixels extracted from an image, im using p5.js and react

Tags: reactjs, image-processing, p5.js

I need to extract pixels from an image, to further manipulate them... but whenever i try to extract the pixels the output is an **incomplete image/canvas.**

I noticed tho, that if i modify the property of the height of the canvas from 480 to... idk... 1400++ i get more pixels extracted, so eventually if i put the height to 5000 i get the whole image...

Tried to preload the image just in case, but actually the image is being imported from my pc *import lady from "./Ladies.jpg"*

```
renderFourth = React.createRef()
componentDidMount() {
    this.sketch = new p5 (p =>{

        var pic;


        p.preload = () =>{
            pic = p.loadImage(lady);
        }

        p.setup = () => {
            p.createCanvas(612,480).parent(this.renderFourth.current)                
        }

        p.draw = () => {
            p.loadPixels();
            pic.loadPixels();
            for(let x = 0; x < p.width; x++){
                for(let y = 0; y < p.height; y++){
                    let loc = (x + y * p.width);
                    p.pixels[loc] = pic.pixels[loc];
                }

            }                
            p.updatePixels();
        }
    })
}

render() {
    return (<div ref={this.renderFourth}></div>)
}
```

theres no current errors nor warnings, and as stated before, whenever i try to extract the pixels from the image, the output is an incomplete image...

Looks like if the for loops aren't working properly.
so its either that or something related to the size is off. because whenever i increase the height to an astronomic number i get the whole image extracted

Answer (score 0):

The [pixels array](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5296bc77afba8baa690002d7/train/javascript) that you get with `getPixels()` stores the info in a  RGBA format, where each of the channels is stored sequentially in one position in the array, which means that, without taking `pixelDensity` into account, the array is 4 times "bigger" than the source. This also explains why you only get the whole image when using a "astronomically high" number.

Try:

```
for(let x = 0; x < p.width; x++){
  for(let y = 0; y < p.height; y++){
    let loc = (x + y * p.width)*4;
    p.pixels[loc] = pic.pixels[loc]; //R
    p.pixels[loc + 1] = pic.pixels[loc + 1]; //G
    p.pixels[loc + 2] = pic.pixels[loc + 2]; //B
    p.pixels[loc + 3] = pic.pixels[loc + 3]; //A
  }
}
```